# How do I sync my Microsoft (DreamSpark) account to a Xamarin account?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, dreamspark

How do I sync my Microsoft (DreamSpark) account to a Xamarin account? In order to use Enterprise features in Xamarin Studio? I was unable to use my outlook email to activate Xamarin Studio Enterprise edition, as well as I was able to activate Xamarin for Visual Studio Enterprise edition. Without Enterprise features I cannot use LLVM compiler on release mode :(

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft give only [Xamarin Studio Community Edition](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=100)  through DreamSpark for Students. Enterprise features are available through the Premium level of [DreamSpark for Academic Institutions](https://www.dreamspark.com/Institution/Subscription.aspx).

In case you have Enterprise features, according to [Xamarin FAQ](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#qp3), you should do the next:

1. Go to the [Visual Studio subscriber portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/manage).
2. Sign in with your Microsoft account which is associated with your *Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN* subscription.
3. Scroll down to **Xamarin Studio (for OS X)** and click *Register and download* link.
4. Create a Xamarin account or sign in with your existing account and Subscribe. They will give you a discount on a full cost of Xamarin Enterprise license.
5. Use the Xamarin account from the step 4 to sign in the Xamarin studio.

Answer (score 0):

With Dreamspark Premium you will get Enterprise features. Check your subscription to see which tier you are in.

To link the accounts, I believe you log into the "My Benefits" area of Dreamspark and look for Xamarin. I don't have access to Dreamspark to confirm the exact area, so I am assuming it's similar to MSDN. Perhaps someone else can confirm.